# parallel projection on a subspace

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, direct-sum

I have a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W$ and it's complement $W'$ $(V = W+W',W\cap W' = \{0\})$

What does it mean that $\pi$ is the projection of $V$ unto $W$ which is ***parallel*** to $W'$?

Does it just mean that it's the projection of $V$ unto $W$? (the notion of parallel being implicit since $W'$ is complement to $W$)

Comment: I thinnk that it is reasonable that it means what you say, parallelism being here something that follows from the orthogonality of $\;W\,,\,\,W^\perp\;$ ... **if that's what is meant** with $\;W'\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I guess $W'$ can be an arbitrary complement of $W$, not necessarily orthogonal, since orthogonality is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Berci Indeed so, but that is why I wrote what I did in the last part of my comment. Also, the assumption of orthogonality doesn't seem too far removed from a reasonable assumption as we're talking of "parallel space", and the only thing related to that that I can think of in this context is orthogonal complement. Also the fact that $\;W\cap W'=0\;$ helps to fortify this idea...but, as you say, it could be meant other thing.

Comment: There is no notion of orthogonality in this case. But we can choose a basis $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ of $V$ such that $W = <e_1,\cdots,e_k>,W' = <e_{k+1},\cdots, e_n>$ and the canonical scalar product on that would make $W$ orthogonal to $W'$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any direct decomposition $V=W\oplus W'$ yields a projection $\pi$ to $W$ defined by $w+w'\mapsto w$. 
The decomposition can be written up made of $\pi$, by $v=\pi(v)\,+\,(v-\pi(v))$. 
Here the summand $\pi(v)$ is parallel to $W$ (actually $\pi(v)\in W$) and $v-\pi(v)$ is parallel to $W'$.

However, I would rather emphasize here that this projection is *parallel* to $W'$, meaning that $v-\pi(v)\in W'$ for all $v\in V$.

In the specific case (for Euclidean spaces) when $W'=W^\perp$, we talk about *orthogonal projection*, which acts parallelly to $W^\perp$.

Comment: The question here is *why* would $\; v-\pi(v)\in W'\;$ be the "meaning" of parallelism in a more or less natural way (i.e., without explicit definition) if not related to orthogonal complement?

Comment: @DonAntonia: The notion of parallel projection has nothing to do with orthogonality (and more generally with inner product spaces). The best way to understand it in the real world is to think of parallel perspective.

Comment: When taking the projection of a vector, there are $2$ components, one is parallel to $W$ (actually, in $W$) and the other one is parallel to $W'$. Since we talk about a projection to $W$, the additional information that the direction of the projection is parallel to $W'$ descirbes it all.